# Ionic 4 - ion-input autocomplete from datalist

Tags: html, ionic-framework, autocomplete, ionic4

Question is for ionic 4.
I'm trying ti give a list of vale to ion-input. Since the list contains 200 items I'd like filter the list.
Something like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

I already see this issue:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5702
but the proposal solution doesn't work for Ionic 4:

```
<ion-input list="browsers" name="browser" placeholder="Choose category">
    <ion-label>Browsers</ion-label>
</ion-input>
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer"/>
    <option value="Firefox"/>
    <option value="Chrome"/>
    <option value="Opera"/>
    <option value="Safari"/>
</datalist>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Change `ion-input` to `input list` then you are done

Working Example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-mtbtv1?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
 <ion-content>
 <input list="browsers"  placeholder="Choose category">
      <ion-label>Browsers</ion-label>

    <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer"></option>
        <option value="Firefox"></option>
        <option value="Chrome"></option>
        <option value="Opera"></option>
        <option value="Safari"></option>
    </datalist>
```

Comment: It works. I'm new in ionic and web development.  thought I can use only ionic ui components api ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/components ). Why you use input list ?

Comment: there is mechanism to sort in ionic i will send link to refer ,i have corrected only what you provided code please wait i wll provide link

Comment: I already see serchbar api but it seems unsuitable for me because I have a list of 200 items. I need something like an autocomplete filter...Have you got idea how to use searchbar for my specific case?

Comment: yup i undestand ,how about pagination

Comment: @ChanakaWeerasinghe Bad news, It was working fine on browser but not working on Android or iOS device.